# How to highlight duplicates between two columns?

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets doesn't have a preset conditional formatting for duplicate cells. I need to highlight the cells in column A and B that contains a match/duplicate between the two of them.

Comment: You should show your code (your attempt to do it for yourself).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please clear formatting from ColumnsA:B, select ColumnA and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=countif(B:B,A1)
```

Then select fill of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Select ColumnB and repeat with:

```
=countif(A:A,B1)
```

Comment: Logical as it counts down from A and compares with B. Just wish I thought of this earlier!! Cool thanks!